# formulas to maximize the output

Tags: algorithms, optimization, maximum-principle

Good day, I have a math problem in my game development like this:

I have two numbers (football player skills): Attack skill (AS) and Defend skill (DS). They are in range from 1.0 to 8.0...
now I want to create formulas for every position, that would return the max value for:

- attacker if the AS is max and DS is somwhere around 20% of max (2)
- defender if the DS is MAX and AS is 20% of max
- midfielder if the AS and DS are equal (higher values both of them are better)...

every other AS and DS should be worse for the given position...

I want this to calculate the best position for the player, for example:

**player1 AS=8, DS=2** - best skills for attacker, so the rating should be biggest for this position. For midfielder it should be lower and for defender even more lower

**player2 AS=8, DS=4** - not the best attacker, but he has **close attacker rating to player1**. He has a **little higher midfielder rating than player1**. But still the attacker rating should be better than midfielder rating. He has also higher defender rating than player1, but **the grow is not as big** as in midfielder rating

**player3 AS=8, DS=5** - not the best midfielder, nor attacker but the rating should be **similar for both positions**, but not as good as player2 has attacking rating, nor as good as player4 as midfielder

**player4 AS=8, DS=6** - similarly to player2 but with switched positions, so better midfielder than attacker

**player5 AS=8, DS=8** - best midfielder. And there is a problem with my tries, I couldnt make this worse attacker rating than player1

**player6 AS=2, DS=8** - best skills for defender

some other examples

- AS=8 DS=8 midfield rating should be equal than attacker rating AS=8 DS=2 and equal as defender rating for AS=2 DS=8
- AS=8 DS=8 attacker/defender rating should be equal to midfielder rating for AS=8 DS=2 or AS=2 DS=8
- AS=5 DS=5 is a little better midfielder rating than would be AS=7 DS=5 (i know maybe
  weird)
- AS=7 DS=5 can be equal midfielder rating as AS=4 DS=4 (they
  are both 2 points away from AS=5 DS=5)

my tries were like: AR = 0.75AS + 0.25DS

the problem was the attacker 8 8 was better then 8 2 and very few combinations give me best rating for midfielder
then i tried

AR = 0.9(AS - DS) + 0.1(DS-AS) and such things but i think it will be something more complicated :(

I hope it is clear enough (EN is not my mother lang) and that there are no collisions in my rules, if you need more examples, ore some concrete, feel free to ask in comments, i will update the question

thanks everyone for help

PS: not sure if I choosed the tags correctly

Comment: you have $100$ cases, you can define ratings for each case.

Comment: maybe i dont understand but i think no, I need only 3 formulas for position ratings, that will be evaluated for a player and according to the biggest result, that will be the best position for a player

Comment: but why would $7,5$ be a worse midfield than $5,5$. Midfield is relative to attack or defence. $DM's$ have better defensive skills than attack. $CAM's$ have better attacking skills than defense while $CM's$ balance both attack and defense. You have to prioritize the midfield for either attack or defense oriented.

Comment: thanks for your interest, i understand you - yes, if it would be CAM, it would have for example AR=7 DR=4 as best choice... but i have only CMs for siplicity for the first game version. 5 5 is better midfielder because 7 5 is more affected with attack, therefore i decided that midfielders should have equally divided skills... if it wouldnt be your way, none of the player would have the CM as best position, every players even 8 8 would be better as attacker or defender than midfielder. Isnt possible to create such formula that could prioritize equall skill splitting?

Comment: there is $7,5$ and $5,5$. The later is a better midfielder that the former because his attacking skills is equal to his defensive skills. In your case, what would you give the later for midfield points. You gave too many examples and they are difficult to put together. Take these three examples and tell me how you will distribute position points. Player$1$ $(7,3)$, Player$2$ $(4,8)$, and Player$3$ $(5,5)$. To each of these players what would you give for attack points, defense and midfield points?

Comment: hm i tried to make a table of most combinations and i run into few collisions mainly because of the negative effect of some cases that i wanted, they should look like this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnjidDgr4QMAdEJvLVBxdl9zSExCWFBtZFNCLW50LWc&usp=sharing

i thing i will need to make for every position one primary and one secondary attribute.. that will be easy, but i didnt want to have more attributes :( anyway thanks, it looks like there is no solution for the problem in the current state :(

Comment: there is always a solution, you just have to reduce the complication of the problem.